# Python module path (relative in flask, absolute in celery)

Tags: python, import, flask, redis, beaker

I am using beaker cache to cache the output of a function.

When I invalidate the cache from flask uwsgi app, it did not reflect in celery app and vice versa.

On further investigation found that beaker using `inspect.getsourcefile(func)` for unique key to store in redis.

Now the problem is:
In flask uwsgi app, the path to load function shows up as

> ./myproject/db_api.py

while in celery it shows up as:

> /opt/myproject/db_api.py.

How do I make sure that the `inspect.getsourcefile(func)` function returns same path in both cases?

Either making celery set the path as ./myporject/db_api.py or flask load the path as /opt/myproject/db_api.py is fine.

Celery is being [run as a daemon](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html) with `CELERYD_CHDIR='/opt'` in /etc/default/celeryd. In `celeryconfig.py` I have `CELERY_IMPORTS = ('myproject.controllers.celerytasks.cache_invalidate')`

Flask is being run by uwsig with an .ini file on ubuntu with following config:

```
[uwsgi]
module = myproject
callable = app
chdir = /opt
```

Comment: How are you starting Flask vs. Celery?

Comment: Flask thru uwsgi and celery as a daemon with /etc/init.d/celeryd

Comment: the relevant configurations will help us see what's going on.  I have a theory, and it involves `cwd` :-)

Comment: I have checked os.getcwd and in all cases it is /opt. Even sys.path are same.